# How to have the value with existing data in Select2 multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

Here is my script for select2 multiple select box. I am using ajax for fetching the data. I need to add the current selections with existing values.

Ex : If 1000,1001 is already in the list. And if the user types 1002 it should merge with the old result and display as 1000, 1001, 1002.

Here is how i place the values in select2

In php i construct the options

```
foreach ($zips as $zipcodes) {
    $pinLists .= $zipcodes->zipcode_id . ',';
    $htmlElements .= '<li class="select2-selection__choice" title=""><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>' . $zipcode->zipcode_id . '</li>';
}
```

Then in html i append to it

```
var htmlElement = '<?php echo $htmlElement ?>';
$(".firstSelect").append(htmlElement);
```

I tried like

```
$(".firstSelect").on('change', function(e) {
    $(".firstSelect").append(htmlElement);
});
```

But i can't able to place the old values on change action.

Here is my entire script of select2 ajax

```
$("#firstList").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "../getZipList",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {

                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
                //console.log(data.it)
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page  

    });
```

How can i do this. Help pls

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that replicates the issue? It seems you're messing with some classes of select2 after it is initialized (`class="select2-selection__choice"`) and I don't understand why. Also, the behavior you describe is quite common and available in the examples (that is, unless I'm missing something, so if you can provide a fiddle, that would be great). Thanks.